# Xcode is treating my iOS app as a Mac app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macos, xcode6

I have been working on an app for a while. I recently saved it to a flash drive and worked on it using another computer. When I returned to using my original computer, the options to run in the simulators have changed to "my Mac." How can I change this back so I can test my app in the iPhone simulators? Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you ever heard about _version tracking_ systems? or GIT repos? duplicating and merging the project again can have painful aftermaths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Manage schemes (by clicking to your app name):

[image]

Delete all the schemes, then click `Autocreate schemes now` button, and tell if it works.